# Different domains for (apparently) equivalent functions

Tags: analysis, functions, logarithms

Let's look at:

$f_1(x)=ln(x^2-4)$

$f_2(x)=ln(x-2)+ln(x+2)$

Every high school student can tell they are the same,
but the first is defined only for $\{x<-2\}\cup\{x>2\}$,
and the latter is defined only for $\{x>2\}$.

Do I miss something? I thought  $ln(xy)=ln(x)+ln(y)$  is always true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different functions since they have different domain, but they have the same values on their common domain. And the law $ln(xy)=ln(x)+ln(y)$ is true if and only if $x,y>0$.

Comment: Thanks! didn't pay attention to the fact that $ln(xy)=ln(x)+ln(y)$ iff $x,y>0$ .